# How to get total number of rows after conditional query search

Tags: sql, blockchain

I'm running a query search of consecutive blocks on the bitcoin blockchain looking for consecutive blocks that were mined more than 2 hours apart. The code I have below works perfectly and returns all the values that I'm looking for, but I'm struggling with getting the code to output the COUNT(*) of all the rows from my query. I'm new to SQL and have managed to get the code to output exactly what I need so far. I would just like to get a count output, I've manually counted and it should be 152.

This is the query site that I am using since I do not have the tech specs to set up a node and have the whole blockchain available to run on my computer. https://blockchainsql.io/

Thank you all in advance.

```
SELECT
    B1.Height AS FromBlock, 
    B2.Height AS ToBlock, 
    B1.TimeStampUtc AS FromTime,
    B2.TimeStampUtc AS ToTime,
    IIF(B2.TimeStampUTC < B1.TimeStampUTC, '-', '') +  
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar, (DATEDIFF(SECOND, B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC) / 86400)), 2) + ':' + 
    CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ss, DATEDIFF(SECOND, IIF(B1.TimeStampUTC < B2.TimeStampUTC, B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC), IIF(B2.TimeStampUTC > B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC, B1.TimeStampUTC)), 0), 108) 
    AS Duration_DDHHMMSS,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC) as DurationSeconds
FROM 
    Block B1 INNER JOIN
    Block B2 ON B1.Height = B2.Height - 1
WHERE
    B1.BranchID = 1 AND  -- Ignore orphaned blocks
    B2.BranchID = 1 AND  -- Ignore orphaned blocks
    (DATEDIFF(SECOND, B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC) >=  7200 OR DATEDIFF(SECOND, B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC) <= -7200)
ORDER BY
    Duration_DDHHMMSS DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    B1.Height AS FromBlock, 
    B2.Height AS ToBlock, 
    B1.TimeStampUtc AS FromTime,
    B2.TimeStampUtc AS ToTime,
    IIF(B2.TimeStampUTC < B1.TimeStampUTC, '-', '') +  
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar, (DATEDIFF(SECOND, B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC) / 86400)), 2) + ':' + 
    CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ss, DATEDIFF(SECOND, IIF(B1.TimeStampUTC < B2.TimeStampUTC, B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC), IIF(B2.TimeStampUTC > B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC, B1.TimeStampUTC)), 0), 108) 
    AS Duration_DDHHMMSS,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC) as DurationSeconds
FROM 
    Block B1 INNER JOIN
    Block B2 ON B1.Height = B2.Height - 1
WHERE
    B1.BranchID = 1 AND  -- Ignore orphaned blocks
    B2.BranchID = 1 AND  -- Ignore orphaned blocks
    (DATEDIFF(SECOND, B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC) >=  7200 OR DATEDIFF(SECOND, B1.TimeStampUTC, B2.TimeStampUTC) <= -7200)
ORDER BY
    Duration_DDHHMMSS DESC;
```

And then run a second query

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

But it would just be so much simpler to count the result set in the programming language you are using.
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is mostly useful when using Limit inside the query